# Using v-bind in css to bind variables to css properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

View does not see this style. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="div">div</div>

color = 'red'

.div {
  background: v-bind(color);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: not sure you can do that (would be good if you could), instead on the div do `:class="['div', color || '']"` and add `&.red{background:red}` inside the `.div` declaration

Comment: If you post source code as screenshot, we can't use the code to reproduce the problem. Please post your source code always as text in a `code block`.  You can now edit your question to replace the screenshot with the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine with Vue3, I did not see any issue in dynamic style binding.

[image]

Here is the live demo **:**

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<template id="appTemplate">
    <div class="div">div</div>
</template>

<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({
  template: document.getElementById("appTemplate").innerHTML,
  data() {
    return {
      color: 'red'
    };
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.div {
  background-color: v-bind(color);
}
</style>
```